# Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON. Utilizing express and parsing error. Any suggestions would be great

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, parsing

For the past few days, I have been attempting to solve this error. I am extremely baffled, as I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When I attempt to get data from node.js in my client side js, my JSON parser is giving me an error:

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (something.js:18:29)
```

I am using node, js, and html for this, 3 files total.
Here is the index.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('hello')
});
app.listen(8080);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/testing/thisshit', async function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var dataToSendToClient = '{"message":"potatohead"}';
  res.send(dataToSendToClient);
});
```

The html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div>hellow world</div>

  <script src="something.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

The client-side JS:

```
console.log('testing')
var abcd = {juice: "juice"}
  $.post( '/testing/thisshit', abcd);
var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/testing/thisshit';
res.open('GET',url,true); // set this to POST if you would like
res.addEventListener('load',onLoad);
res.addEventListener('error',onError);
res.send();
function onLoad() {
  var response = this.responseText;
  console.log(response);
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log("the result: " + parsedResponse)
}
function onError() {
  console.log('error');
}
```

No matter what I attempt, it seems to baffle me. Any answers or suggestions would be incredibly helpful, and thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow. hahaha my bad. After 10 hours of a gruelling search trying to solve this, I finally solved this.

`res.open('get')` was supposed to be `res.open('post')`.